# Finding parameters of exponentially decaying sinusoids (Matrix Pencil Method)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing, complex-numbers, exponential

The matrix pencil method is an algorithm which can be used to find the individual exponential decaying sinusoids' parameters (frequency, amplitude, decay factor and initial phase) in a signal consisting of multiple such signals added. I am trying to implement the algorithm. The algorithm can be found in the paper from this link:

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=370583 OR
http://krein.unica.it/~cornelis/private/IEEE/IEEEAntennasPropagMag_37_48.pdf

In order to test the algorithm, I created a synthetic signal composed of four exponentially decaying sinusoids generated as follows:

```
fs=2205;
t=0:1/fs:249/fs;
f(1)=80;
f(2)=120;
f(3)=250;
f(4)=560;
a(1)=.4;
a(2)=1;
a(3)=0.89;
a(4)=.65;
d(1)=70;
d(2)=50;
d(3)=90;
d(4)=80;
for i=1:4
    x(i,:)=a(i)*exp(-d(i)*t).*cos(2*pi*f(i)*t);
end
y=x(1,:)+x(2,:)+x(3,:)+x(4,:);
```

I then feed this signal to the algorithm described in the paper as follows:

```
function [f d] = mpencil(y)

%construct hankel matrix
N = size(y,2);
L1 = ceil(1/3 * N);
L2 = floor(2/3 * N);
L = ceil((L1 + L2) / 2);

fs=2205;
for i=1:1:(N-L)
    Y(i,:)=y(i:(i+L));
end

Y1=Y(:,1:L);
Y2=Y(:,2:(L+1));

[U,S,V] = svd(Y);
D=diag(S);
tol=1e-3;
m=0;
l=length(D);
for i=1:l
    if( abs(D(i)/D(1)) >= tol)
        m=m+1;
    end
end
Ss=S(:,1:m);
Vnew=V(:,1:m);
a=size(Vnew,1);
Vs1=Vnew(1:(a-1),:);
Vs2=Vnew(2:end,:);
Y1=U*Ss*(Vs1');
Y2=U*Ss*(Vs2');
D_fil=(pinv(Y1))*Y2;
z = eig(D_fil);

l=length(z);
for i=1:2:l
    f((i+1)/2)= (angle(z(i))*fs)/(2*pi);
    d((i+1)/2)=-real(z(i))*fs;
end
```

In the output from the above code, I am correctly getting the four constituent frequency components but am not getting their decaying factors. If anybody has prior experience with this algorithm or has some understanding about why this discrepancy might be there, I would be very grateful for your help. I have tried rewriting the code from a scratch multiple times but it has been of no help, giving the same results.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

There are two small glitches in the code:

1. SVD output is a complex conjugate of the right singular matrix—i.e, `Vh`—and [according to IEEE](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=370583), it needs to be converted to `V` first.

   Now, this `V` is filtered for reducing the dimension.

   After reducing the dimensions of `V`, `V1` and `V2` are calculated from `V`. (In your case, you are using `Vh` directly for calculating `V1` and `V2`!)

   When calculating `Y1` and `Y2`, the complex conjugates of `V1` and `V2` are used.
2. You did not consider the absolute magnitude of complex eigen values, but only the real part.

   ```
   damping coefficient "zeta"= log(magnitude(z))/Ts
   ```